# How to pass runtime environment variables to client side in NuxtJS SSR application

Tags: vuejs2, axios, environment-variables, nuxt.js

My NuxtJS applications makes HTTP request to a backend API. I am using `nuxtjs/axios` pluging to make these requests. I have configured base URL for API in `nuxt.config.js` like below

```
axios: {
  baseURL: process.env.BASE_URL,
},
```

**In Local**, I have a `.env` like below

> BASE_URL=http://localhost:8080

**On AWS ECS Container**, I have declared environment variable with

> Key: `BASE_URL` and Value: `https://example.com`

On running the application following happens

- When application is server-side rendered, base URL for API is resolved correctly e.g `https://example.com/previews`
- When application is client-side rendered, base URL for API is not resolved to `https://example.com` but rather to the same IP address that my web application is accessible on.

So, what I understand might be happening is, that the `process.env.BASE_URL` is not getting passed from the `server-side(NodeJS server)` to `client-side(Web Browser)`. Hence it is falling back to the application's IP address.

Any idea why such a behavior and how to pass the environment variable to client-side as well? Or what might be causing this.

Thanks.

Comment: Are you sure you did not missed another declaration of `localhost` somewhere in your code? Also, maybe try to manually set `browserBaseURL` https://axios.nuxtjs.org/options#browserbaseurl Or maybe double check on some other platform.

Comment: Also, please share your `nuxt.config.js` file. It may help.

Comment: @kissu it is not `localhost` that gets resolved but the IP of web application. I think the `axios` part of the `nuxt.config.js` I have shared in the question. No other parts of the configuration are related with API URL.

Comment: Not sure how to help you here unfortunately, without further debugging details. Maybe try to make a [repro]?